# Unable to retrieve data from jqGrid in beforeSelectRow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

**Im using a jqGrid:**

```
colModel: [  
    { name: 'IdTarifaAcceso', index: 'IdTarifaAcceso', hidden: true },

    { name: 'TipoTension.IdTipoTension', index: 'TipoTension.IdTipoTension' , hidden: true},

    { name: 'DsTarifaAcceso', index: 'DsTarifaAcceso', width: (pageWidth * (9.9 / 100)), stype: 'text', align: "center" },

    { name: 'TipoTension.DsTipoTension', index: 'IdTarifaAcceso', hidden: true }
],

beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {

            var $self = $(this),

                iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]),

                cm = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

            var rowData = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
```

When I want get the value of TipoTension.DsTipoTension in the beforeSelectRow section, I get the error of null reference:

```
    var = rowData.TipoTension.IdTipoTension;
```

}

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The `.` character has special meaning in JavaScript. You can't have it in a variable name, because it's the property access operator.  I'd suggest using `_` instead if you need a word separator other than just camelCase.

Comment: Of course you know "var = rowData.whatever" is not valid syntax.  

What does rowData equal in beforeSelectRow?

Comment: TipoTension.DsTipoTension is a subobject, I can not use _ because the value is not shown, I can not reference the object with _ , the object is TipoTension.DsTipoTension and TipoTension is a subobject of another object, not a variable.

Comment: Finally I resolved it with the next sintax:        rowData['TipoTension.IdTipoTension']